# Not able to locate a bootstrap dropdown element in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to locate the dropdown and select an option. The code i used is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\nithi\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://parivahan.gov.in/parivahan/')

VehicleServicesButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block-block-9"]/div/div[1]/p/a')

VehicleServicesButton.click()

OtherStatesButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="node-1978"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/a/div/img') 

OtherStatesButton.click()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.find_element_by_id('state_cd_label').click()
```

I am getting the following error on last line of code.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="state_cd_label"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Here is the html code and website!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to do it. On clicking on the image the new tab is opened so to operate on the new window you have to switch driver focus on the new tab from the parent tab.

Once you do this the exception will go away.

To switch to the new tab just add this code before last line of the above code

```
p = driver.current_window_handle
print("Parent window"+p)
chwd = driver.window_handles
print( chwd)
driver.switch_to.window(chwd[1])
```

**Output** -

[image]